# tangent line and $dx$

Tags: calculus

Is it not a paradox that the tangent line to a function $f(x)$ only intersects the function at one point while the derivative is $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ in which $dx$ is a small nonzero quantity encompassing more than one point so that the tangent line can be formed with information near $x$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The quantity $dy/dx$ is a function of only one point on the curve $y=f(x).$

Comment: No, it is not a paradox, since the derivative is defined to be a limit. "$dx$" is not actually a small quantity. What you describe are called "secant lines" for a small quantity $\Delta x$. The derivative is the limit of $\Delta f(x)/\Delta x$ as $\Delta x \to 0$. The tangent line is the limit of the secant lines (it is not itself actually a secant line).

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will view $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ as a confusing notation and instead use the limit definition with a geometrical picture in mind.